# How apache route intercept request to rest methods?

Tags: rest, apache-camel

In my project, RESTful services are built with Apache CAMEL. I  could not understand few concepts.

1) If Camel route intercept the request why we need to write @GET @POST story and all. We can write invoke method from Camel route rite?

Kindly help me understand the process.

Also, what is cxfrs:endpoint and cxfrs:reserver? Do i need to use both?

Answer (score 0):

If you build a RESTful service with Camel, Camel just leverage CXF to handle the request, so you still need to follow the rules of CXF.

Because there are quit configuration differences between the REST Server and REST Client, we use
cxfrs:server and cxfrs:client separately for the server and client side configuration.